# How to fix 'Selecting rows without null or blank value in each column'?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Im having trouble using this code here:

```
select *
from toadd
where pcode = '' or pcode is null or
      brand = '' or brand is null or
      description = '' or description is null;
```

I am trying to return values that doesn't have null or blank value within them columns above.

My problem is: I have coded the query to only return values that are only null or blank values see if it actually works and then Ill use a delete statement based on that query.

But it still returns columns with filled data, even tho I have said not to show any values that are filled in the query.

Not sure why its doing this?

All my columns types are set up as `VARCHAR` I have mix data with text and numbers.

Here is my table layout:

```
Table: outerb
Columns:
id int(11) AI PK 
pcode varchar(255) 
brand varchar(255) 
description varchar(255) 
size varchar(255) 
barcode varchar(255)
```

This is what it looks like currently

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H93In.png)

this is my expected result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8pU5.png)

Comment: Add a constraint that refuses zero-length strings.

Comment: Based on your recent photo addition of expected output, you actually don't want any result that will return either three of those as ('' or NULL), correct?

Comment: Yeah thats correct, let me rewrite my question alittle bit. Thanks for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want rows where all of the tested columns are not empty or not null

```
select * 
from toadd 
where !(pcode = '' or pcode is null) AND
      !(brand = '' or brand is null) AND
      !(description = '' or description is null);
```

If you want to exclude rows where one or more of the columns are empty or null

```
select * 
from toadd 
where !(pcode = '' or pcode is null) OR
      !(brand = '' or brand is null) OR
      !(description = '' or description is null);
```

Comment: Hi, this query returns me 0 values. I have attached some images in question and updated the question slightly for better understanding

Comment: quick question what does the `!` do?

Comment: it's a negation, same as NOT.

Answer (score 1):

change outer `or` condition to `and`

```
     select * from toadd where (pcode = '' or pcode is null) and
     ( brand = '' or brand is null) and
      (description = '' or description is null)
```

Comment: This returns me no 0 rows. I have updated my question and added in my table structure

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired result using the following SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM `outerb ` 
WHERE Length(`pcode `) > 0 
AND Length(`brand `) >0 
AND Length(`description `) > 0
```